# Ignoring vectors containing NaN entries in Matlab calculations

Tags: matlab, dynamic-data, finance, nan, quantitative-finance

This code prices bonds according to the [fitSvensson](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/finfixed/fitsvenssonirfunctioncurve.html) function. How do I get Matlab to ignore NaN values in the CleanPrice vector when a date is selected for which some bonds have a NaN entry for a missing price. How can I get it to ignore that bond altogether when deriving the zero curve? It seems many solutions to NaNs resort to interpolation or setting to zero, but this will lead to an erroneous curve.

```
Maturity=gcm3.data.CouponandMaturity(1:36,2);

[r,c]=find(gcm3.data.CleanPrice==datenum('11-May-2012'));
row=r

SettleDate=gcm3.data.CouponandMaturity(row,3);
Settle = repmat(SettleDate,[length(Maturity) 1]);

CleanPrices =transpose(gcm3.data.CleanPrice(row,2:end));
CouponRate = gcm3.data.CouponandMaturity(1:36,1);
Instruments = [Settle Maturity CleanPrices CouponRate];
PlottingPoints = gcm3.data.CouponandMaturity(1,2):gcm3.data.CouponandMaturity(36,2);
Yield = bndyield(CleanPrices,CouponRate,Settle,Maturity);

SvenssonModel = IRFunctionCurve.fitSvensson('Zero',SettleDate,Instruments)
ParYield=SvenssonModel.getParYields(Maturity);
```

The Data looks like this where each column is a bond, column 1 is the dates and the elements the clean price. As you can see, the first part of the data contains lots of NaNs for bonds yet to have prices. After a point all bonds have prices but unfortunately there are instances where one or two day's prices are missing. 
Ideally, if a NaN is present I would like it to ignore that bond on that date if possible as the more curves generated (irrespective of number of bonds used) the better. If this is not possible then ignoring that date is an option but will result in many curves not generating.
   [image: CleanPrice data]

Comment: Can you provide example input data? Do you want it to ignore that bond in its entirety, or that date, or just that bond on that date? I imagine it would have to be one of the first two options.

Comment: Check out `isnan` to write your own handler, and preexisting NaN handling functions such as `nanmean`.

Comment: @Dan. Thank you- I have edited the question to include more info. If it is possible to remove 'that bond on that date' that would be excellent for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general solution to your problem.  I don't have that toolbox on my work computer so I can't test whether it works with the IRFunctionCurve.fitSvensson command

```
[row,~]=find(gcm3.data.CleanPrice(:,1)==datenum('11-May-2012'));
col_set=find(~isnan(gcm3.data.CleanPrice(row,2:end)));
CleanPrices=transpose(gcm3.data.CleanPrice(row,col));
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated the refs to col and row and it works great.Thx! Although if you can help in this I would be v.grateful: I now have it in a for-loop for nTrials of successive SettleDates **but** I have a problem when calculating an array of prices: Diff=PriceActual-PriceNSS where [PriceActual, AccruedIntActual] = bndprice(Yield, CouponRate, Settle, Maturity);
[PriceNSS, AccruedIntNSS] = bndprice(ParYield, CouponRate, Settle, Maturity); As Diff emerges as (nTrials x col) array where (col=<36). It should be a fixed (nTrials x 36) size where the gaps are 0 so that Diff element matches bond.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, but let me try to restate it: because you're not including every bond on every date, the number of bonds you're returning prices for varies by date.  To fix this, you've got to either save or recreate which bond your good (not NaN) prices came from.  The easiest way to do this is: `col_good = setdiff(2:26,col); PriceActual=zeros(1,25); accruedInActual=zeros(1,25); [PriceActual(1,col_good), accruedInActual(1,col_good)] = bndPrice(ParYield,CouponRate,Settle,Maturity);` the original setdiff basically says "give me the indices where the good columns will be placed